# How to use enum to determine which item to use from an import in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

### Overview

We have a module that exports objects from other files.

For simplicity sake, let's call this `Vehicle`. It exports `Car`, `Boat`, and `Plane`.

We have an enum that corresponds to these vehicles, let's say the following:

```
enum Vehicles {
    Car,
    Boat,
    Plane,
}
```

We are looking to use the enum to specify which imported object we should then use.

---

### Question

We're aware that we can do a switch/case, but this becomes unnecessarily long as our enum grows. Some of our classes export dozens of variations of objects that we then use elsewhere (we are unable to use types/interfaces to simplify).

```
switch(vehicle) {
    case Vehicles.Car: {
        return Car;
    }
    case Vehicles.Boat: {
        return Boat;
    }
    case Vehicles.Plane: {
        return Plane;
    }
}
```

---

#### More info

We are using TypeScript with Svelte. The import is a package (e.g. Google Charts [charts], fortawesome [icons], etc.). We are looking to create a sort of wrapper to easily initialize specific components.

Example:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { a, b, c } from x
    const y = () => {
        // logic here
    }
</script>

<y/>
```

<sub>This question seems to be TypeScript-specific, so I've purposely left out svelte tag from my question</sub>

Comment: You could try to create an interface with your enum and call this interface in the logic.

Comment: @AntoineKurka would you elaborate on your idea? I'd like to see what you're thinking.

Comment: @AntoineKurka what do you mean? You cannot use an interface in emitted runtime code.

Comment: @ctwheels why do you even need an enum? Do you get a user input?

Comment: @blaumeise20 using some dev tools yes. For example, building our components library with Storybook, rather than having hundreds of component pages, we’re opting to have one with the ability to change the component in a drop down. We’re creating wrappers for some imports (like Google Charts) and the drop down allows us to switch chart type. Not for the end user though.

Answer (score 3):

So I tried some things, here you can see them:

---

#### What I originally wanted to do

I tried to assign the classes to the enum properties, but it didn't work. How I imagined it is like this:

```
enum Vehicle {
    Car = Car,
    Boat = Boat,
    Plane = Plane,
}
```

But TypeScript gives me an error. You can try it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8C+BYAUKSMBCA9mAC4obbhTQAK4AdgKZlZYN0CuAttAGoMAWAS1BNkWaBLiJoAXikIANOMmESs6KuJLMkmvSZzaYRttRA). Why did I think about that? Because you can assign value to enum properties like this:

```
enum Char {
    A = 65,
    B = 66,
    C = 67,
    D = 68,
    // ...
}
```

But as you can see, it doesn't work in your case.

---

#### A possible solution

You could just forget using an enum. There is a special feature in TypeScript, `as const`. It makes an array or object literal constant. That would look somehow like this:

```
const Vehicle = {
    Car,
    Boat,
    Plane
} as const;
```

Why don't I use a value? That is called property shorting (or something like that). When you have a variable or some named thing and want to use it with the same property name, you don't have to specify one. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYCdoG8C+BYAUKSMBCA9mAC4obbhTQAK4AdgKZlZbAF0SkBqDAFgJagmAXhRZoEuIgA04yYRKzMkmvQZZU0SNDYdiAbiA) is the example using the `as const` version.

---

What when you want to get the class by an index?

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys. It look somehow like this:

```
const index = 1;
const keys = Object.keys(Vehicle);
const vehicle = Vehicle[keys[index]];
```

I'm not going to add a link here because it is not really important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map of

```
const vehicleComponentsMap: Record<Vehice, SvelteComponent> = {
   [Vehicle.Car]: Car,
   ....
}
```

And then if you have a convention for the Vehicle implementation files, you can use it to dynamically build this map (by collecting data from files by convention).

Comment: That doesn't really help, because he already mentioned that he doesn't want to create an extra map like a switch. And by the way: You can only use `string` and `number` as object key types.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is largely inspired by blaumeise20.

**Note:** React is just used as an example here. Your imports can be anything

Heres what I came up with:

```
import { Component, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

const imports = { Component, useCallback, useEffect } as const;

function getCorrectImport<K extends keyof typeof imports>(key: K): typeof imports[K] {
  return imports[key];
}
```

You can then call this function like this:

```
getCorrectImport('Component'); // You should get completion hints and correct typings using this
```

**The Downside** is you will need to stuff your imports into an object like I created the `imports` object.

A cool way if you import everything from a module could be something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

function getCorrectImport<K extends keyof typeof React>(key: K): typeof React[K] {
  return React[key];
}

const correctObject = getCorrectImport('Component');
```

This can allow you to not create an object but the downside would be you would need to import everything from the module you are importing from. This works because the `* as React` syntax creates an object for you.

If you can do that, this would be an ideal solution.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwCwAUAPRNyiSxwDecAwiZAB2WQTAA0cAK6osvZABt5AIzwBrCdKwBRAgSz44AXzhES5Snhi1GjFnFwRBqeO2gx0AXm58BjkeKkZOUUVXHVA7V19eGM0e0dnegZGAklBfGBHOABzLBh%20KEp8AElwNwAeAGk4LAAPGBEAE3RVLABPCAI4GDawLE7MKhgAPgAKVraALjhKgEppnr6B7EsAbUqAXW5GODhKGEkoQUG1iY2kwxsGByd4WrgvXPzoIphSjhhRsn4y4VEyWY0IA)

Comment: I think they are using Svelte, not React.

Comment: React is just used as an example. The imports can be anything. I just used React in the playgroud to test typesafety etc.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use this one?

```
enum Vehicle {
Car= 'CAR',
Boat= 'BOAT',
Plane= 'PLANE',
```

}

Regards,
N Baua

Comment: Accessing this enum as Vehicle['Car'] is very much possible and no need to use switch